# Function in DLL always returns null

Tags: c#, c++, dll, pinvoke, dllimport

I'm writing a dll in C++ to get the serial hd, this is the code of the function:

```
__declspec(dllexport) char* __stdcall char* GetSerialHD()
{
     WmiQueryResult res = getWmiQueryResult(L"SELECT SerialNumber FROM Win32_PhysicalMedia", L"SerialNumber");
     char* ret = NULL;
     std::string strValue;
     char* strReturn = NULL;
     for (const auto& item : res.ResultList) {
          strValue.assign(item.begin(), item.end());
          ULONG ulSize = strlen(MyString) + sizeof(char);
          strReturn = (char*)::CoTaskMemAlloc(ulSize);
          strcpy(strReturn, strValue.c_str());
          break;
     }
     return strReturn;
}
```

The dll function calls it from an application written in C#:

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
public static extern string GetSerialHD();

...
string GetHD = GetSerialHD();
```

This function GetSerialHD() always returns null, but the same code in a console application C++ for testing works well.

Comment: My guess is that the WMI query results in 0 matches. That's the only way I can see a `nullptr` being returned from the function.

Comment: You are using c language method so the calling convention is wrong.  StdCall in using windows calling method.

Comment: @jdweng there is nothing wrong with using StdCall, especially since both DLL function and PInvoke agree to use StdCall so there is no mismatch. StdCall is very common for 3rd party DLLs to use on Windows. It is one of the few calling conventions that all compilers for Windows support equally, making cross-compiler interop possible.

Comment: `strlen(MyString)` should be `strlen(strValue.c_str())` or better `strValue.size()`

Comment: @TedLyngmo "*My guess is that the WMI query results in 0 matches. That's the only way I can see a `nullptr` being returned from the function*" - or if `::CoTaskMemAlloc()` fails to allocate memory, but then `strcpy()` should crash

Comment: Note, the C# code is leaking the memory that the DLL allocates. Marshaling a string return value as `LPStr` does not free the memory automatically. The C# code needs to declare the return value as `IntPtr` instead, then use `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi()` to convert the memory to a `String`, and `Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem()` to free the memory.

Comment: @RemyLebeau True indeed. Checking the return value, as one should always do, would confirm that.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau This test function works correctly:

__declspec(dllexport) char* __stdcall FuncA()
    {
        char szSampleString[] = "test";
        ULONG ulSize = strlen(szSampleString) + sizeof(char);
        char* pszReturn = NULL;
        pszReturn = (char*)::CoTaskMemAlloc(ulSize);
        strcpy(pszReturn, szSampleString);
        return pszReturn;
    }

Comment: @0kkult0 technically, it should be more like this : `__declspec(dllexport) char* __stdcall FuncA()
{
char szSampleString[] = "test";
ULONG ulSize = (strlen(szSampleString) + 1) * sizeof(char);
char* pszReturn = (char*) ::CoTaskMemAlloc(ulSize);
if (pszReturn) { strcpy(pszReturn, szSampleString); } return pszReturn; }`